# Enums in C++ - how does a function assign a value

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to understand a C++ code [given here](https://github.com/mcostalba/Stockfish/blob/master/src/types.h). Apologies if the question is too basic, but I am not a regular C++ coder.

Here are two Enums defined in the code and a a few functions that operate on the Enums:

```
...
enum Value {
   VALUE_ZERO = 0, 
   VALUE_DRAW = 0, 
   VALUE_KNOWN_WIN = 10000,
   VALUE_MATE = 32000,
   VALUE_INFINITE = 32001, 
   VALUE_NONE = 32002, 
   ...
   };
...

/// Score enum stores a middlegame and an endgame value in a single integer. 
/// The least significant 16 bits are used to storethe endgame value and
/// the upper 16 bits are used to store the middlegame value. ...
enum Score {
   SCORE_ZERO, 
   SCORE_ENSURE_INTEGER_SIZE_P = INT_MAX,
   SCORE_ENSURE_INTEGER_SIZE_N = INT_MIN
};

inline Score make_score(int mg, int eg) {
   return Score((mg << 16) + eg)
}

/// Extracting the signed lower and upper 16 bits is not so trivial ...
inline Value mg_value(Score s) {
   union {uint16_t u; int16_t s;} mg = {uint16_t(unsigned(s + 0x8000) >> 16)};
   return Value(mg.s);
}

inline Value eg_value(Score s) {
   union {uint16_t u; int16_t s;} eg = {uint16_t(unsigned(s))};
   return Value(eg.s);
}
```

Questions:

(a) From my basic understanding of `Enum` in C++, `SCORE_ZERO` in the enum `Score` gets a value of `0`, and thus the set of values of enum `Score` is `0`, `MAX_INT`, or `MIN_INT`. The function `make_score` seems to accepts any two `int` (`mg`, `eg`) and returns an instance of `Score`. How does it (or the compiler) decide whether to return `Score` with value assigned to one out of `0`, `MAX_INT`, or `MIN_INT`?

(b) Similar, the `Enum` `Value` only has a fixed set of values. How does `Value(mg.s)` in the function `mg_value`, or `Value(eg.s) in the function`eg_value`decide which values from`Value` to pick?

(c) In general, if `XYZ` is an `Enum` and a function returns `XYZ(n)` where `n` is not a value already defined in `Enum`, how is the `Enum` initialized?

Comment: every enum has an underlying integer type. a value of that type will be returned no matter what the actual numeric value is or whether it is part of the enum. if it's not part of the enum, then no problem, it won't compare equal to any member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does it (or the compiler) decide whether to return `Score` with value assigned to one out of `0`, `MAX_INT`, or `MIN_INT`?

It doesn't. When you force a cast to `Score` using `Score((mg << 16) + eg)`, you can use any value, not necessarily one of the above declared constants.

It is valid to use:

```
Score s1 = (Score)10;
Score s2 = Score(20);
```

> How does `Value(mg.s)` in the function `mg_value`, or `Value(eg.s)` in the function `eg_value` decide which values from `Value` to pick?

It doesn't. The answer to the previous question regarding `Score` applies here as well.

> In general, if `XYZ` is an `enum` and a function returns `XYZ(n)` where `n` is not a value already defined in the `enum`, how is the `enum` initialized?

The answer to the first question applies here as well. The compiler doesn't guarantee that the value of a variable of type `XYZ` will be one of the constants defined in the `enum`.

Comment: While I agree that a compiler cannot guarantee anything, most compilers will warn against misuse of enums. E.g. if you switch on an enum, compilers will warn about missing cases and most will whine if you supply a default statement.